# fetching data from a dynamic form in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I've got a json file that generates the form definitions for each specific form. In the view - I spit out the data something like this

```
<input ng-data-model="data[value2.Id]" placeholder="{{value2.Label}}" type="text" />

<button ng-click="send_form()" >Submit</button>
```

In my controller, I've got the following function

```
$scope.send_form = function() {
    alert($scope.data);
}
```

When the send_form function is called - i get "undefined" returned back. My question is, how do i handle dynamic form data in Angular JS and get each of the values inserted by the user? Is there a way to get a key/value pair set of data returned? with the ng-data-model has the key and the value inserted by the user as a user? Or how would i handle this specific scenario? Any help would do :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just `ng-model` to bind your input to your scope variable. Or you can use data-ng-model for compliance. Other than that it should work if your data is set up - might help to show an example of how it looks.

Here's a fiddle with some dummy data:
https://jsfiddle.net/ba0pj6sv/